# Factory reset my ipad but app store still logged into another account

Tags: itunes, apple-id, password

I recently factory reset my ipad through my usb cable connected to my iMac via iTunes. I went through the setup tutorial and logged in using one of my apple IDs. I then went to the app store on the ipad and went to search for an app to download. However, when I was trying to download it, the apple ID that popped up was my old apple ID. Does anybody know how to get the app store to ask me to switch to a different apple ID?

I also checked under Settings. My icloud, iTunes & App Store are both logged into my correct apple ID but when I run the app, it is asking for the password to my old apple ID.

I also checked Mail, contacts, calendars and all are using my new apple ID. Same thing with messages and facetime, both using my new apple ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the App Store app, scroll down to the bottom and see what Apple ID is logged-in.  If it's the wrong one, tap the ID to log off then log-in again.  What happens?

Comment: Ahh.  I see it now. Thanks for your help!  I just needed to change that bottom log-in info.

Comment: I'll add that as the answer and then you can accept it.  It will also help others who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the *App Store* app, be sure to scroll to the bottom of the main page and sign out.  Then tap *Sign in* and log in as the correct Apple ID.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe they have so many areas to sign in. It almost kind of defeats the purpose of having a supposedly "unifying" account.